# Moving client to a workgroup when the domain machine account doesn't exist

Tags: windows, powershell, dns, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I'm working on some automation in our test environment where we have powershell scripts to join a windows client to either a domain or a workgroup.

I'm having trouble trying to move a windows 7 client from a domain to a workgroup, in the case where the client's machine account doesn't exist in the domain.

Here is the code:

```
$User = administrator
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "<password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$DomainCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $User, $Password
remove-computer -credential $DomainCred -force -passthru -verbose
```

This is the error that is returned:

```
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Remove-Computer" on Target "localhost".

Remove-Computer: This command cannot be executed on target computer ('xxx')
due to following error: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
At line :1 char:16
+ remove-computer <<<<  -credential $DomainCred -force -passthru -verbose
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (xxx:String) [Remove-Computer],
    InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Powershell.
    Commands.RemoveComputerCommand
```

However, if I try this using the GUI (Computer Properties, Advanced system settings, Computer Name , Change...), it prompts for credentials and succeeds.

How would I replicate this operation into the powershell command so that it can be done pragmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Add-Computer`, like this (untested):

```
Add-Computer -WorkgroupName "WORKGROUP" -Force
```

AFAIK the only difference between `Add-Computer` and `Remove-Computer` is that `Remove-Computer` also disables the computer account, which would probably give you this error since the computer account doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried this, but got the same error message back.  (Also, the -Force flag is not supported in Powershell on Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

I have two options.

Option 01

```
$Workgroup = "CL-01" #IF you want to add computer to domain edit here(Domain name)
$Password = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$Username = "$Workgroup\Username"
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$Password)
Add-Computer -WorkGroup $Workgroup -Credential $credential
Restart-Computer -Force
```

Option 2 and why Option 2 Storing a password in a script is not such a favorable option so I suggest taking up option 2

```
$Workgroup = "CL-01"#IF you want to add computer to domain edit here(Domain name)
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password for $user" -AsSecureString
$Username = "$Workgroup\Username" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$Password)
Add-Computer -WorkGroup $Workgroup -Credential $credential
Restart-Computer -Force
```

Note: Run the all the Scripts as Administrator!!

Hope this will help!! Cheers!!

Comment: I Tried option 1, but received permissions denied when trying to use the workgroup (didn't matter what creds I provided).  I also tried the domain option, but received the error message I originally received (no mappings was done).  Any more ideas?

Comment: Answer For the 1st Issue (Its matter if you are using a account that doesn't have domain Administrator privileges or local administrator) when adding the computer from the domain to work group use Local Administrator credentials not Domain and another reason is that you must be using a account that doesn't have local admin privileges. So always use right credentials.

Comment: Answer for the 2nd issue as follow

Reason
-A SAM account name was renamed on the client computers.
-An account does not exist on domain member computers.
-A SAM account name differs from its domain account name.
-The client is running a Multilingual User Interface Pack (MUI) that     uses a different default language than the domain controller.

Check again. Have a nice day :)

Note : Everything i put on this site is tested by myself alone therefore i can ensure that it will work 100% :) 

For More Info : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890737